# How to assign div value to php variable using Jquery Ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery, html

I have a href tag, in that i wrote onclick func,

```
<a href="#" id="thumb" class="thumb" onclick="doThumb('<?php echo the_ID(); ?>');"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio_thumbs'); ?></a>
```

in the onclick() function the code is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function doThumb(temp) 
   var tempThmb = temp;
   document.getElementById("selectedResult").innerHTML=tempThmb;
   return tempThmb;
}
</script>
```

the returned value, im printing it in an empty div.

```
<div id="selectedResult" name="selectedResult"></div>';
```

Now my issue is, im getting the result in the empty div, but i have to pass the value of the div to $my_postid.

```
$my_postid = "Should pass the value here";//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
```

How can i achieve this do i have to use ajax jquery, kindly help me....

Comment: Explore your question more. On what event you want to assign value to `$my_postid`? On same event or any other event like form submit etc...?

Comment: href tag is where i click an image, and clicking the image through JS im passing the post id associated with image, that id i have to pass it to $my_postid dynamically....

Comment: the same event is applied here also

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the way you are doing. PHP is server side language and javascript is client side. One way to do this is to send an ajax request at `onclick` event of your image. And send the `id` in ajax request. The ajax will get the post on the base of that id and will return you. Then you can show that post content any where.

**update after receiving code of questioner**

You don't need to do initial operation in your function. Just change it as below.

```
 function doThumb(temp) {
        var $mainCats=temp;
        alert ($mainCats);
        $.ajax ( {
            url:"<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:'action=my_special_ajax_callc&main_catidc=' + $mainCats,
            onsuccess : function(data) {
                $("#selectedResults").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                $("#selectedResults").append(data); 
            }
       } );
   }
```

Comment: $(function()           {
$('#selectedResult').click(function()
{
var $mainCats=$('#selectedResult').val();
alert ($mainCats);
$.ajax
(
{
url:"<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",    
type:'POST',
data:'action=my_special_ajax_callc&main_catidc=' + $mainCats,
{
$("#selectedResults").removeAttr("disabled");
$("#selectedResults").append(results);
}
}
);
});
});

Comment: @SolomonHenry your code of ajax code was wrong. I have updated my answer, check it now.

Comment: Now the function doThumb() is returning the post_id to the empty <div> that is selectedResult, i have to grab that result and pass it to the code ---------> $my_postid = "Should pass the value here";//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid); now can you kindly tell me where shall i put this code, can i put this code in the function doThumb(). im not a pro, so kindly bare with me